# How to compare value with value afterwards in a list?

Tags: python

```
x = [1,2,3,4,50,6,3,2,3,8]
for i in x:
  if i > x[x.index(i)+1:10]:
    print(i)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

I want to determine which number is larger than all the numbers afterward, in this circumstance, 50.
However, came out this error.
Does anyone have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Consider using max(x) to get the value of the largest element in list x.

Comment: `index(i)` is the slow way to get an index.  Use `for pos,i in enumerate(x)` to get the index and value at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    if all(x[i] > x[j] for j in range(i + 1, len(x))):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It actually worked. But one more question, if the last number in list,x is the largest, they will print it out. May i know why?

Comment: @JieHangLee `all()` will default to true if there are no elements for it to check. If you want it to not count in that case, then you can just add `and j + 1 < len(x)` to the condition

Answer (score 1):

Please try these simple solutions and see which one fits best for your need. I have left comments briefly explaining what each case does. Keep coding in Python, it is a great computer language, pal!

```
numbers_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 50, 6, 3, 2, 3, 8]

# 1- Fast approach using built in max function
print("Using Max Built-in function: ", max(numbers_lst))

# 2- Manual Approach iterating all the elements of the list
max_num = numbers_lst[0]

for n in numbers_lst:
    max_num = n if n >= max_num else max_num

print("Manual Iteration: ", max_num)

# 3- Using comprehensions, in this case for the list
max_num = numbers_lst[0]
[max_num:=n for n in numbers_lst if n >= max_num]
print("List Comprehension: ", max_num)

# 4- Sort the list in ascending order and print the last element in the list.
numbers_lst.sort()

# printing the last element, which is in this case the largest one
print("Using the sort list method:", numbers_lst[-1])

# 5 - Using the built in sorted function and getting the last list element afterwards
sorted_lst = sorted(numbers_lst, reverse=True)
max_num = sorted_lst[0]
print("Sorted List: ", max_num)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, pal. will continue to code knowing there's someone so nice and helpful out here!

Comment: We are happy to assist, buddy. Hopefully I don't get banned for saying this.:)

Answer (score 0):

Although answer given by @Green Cloak Guy is a perfectly valid answer, it is inefficient as it is `O(n^2)` solution. I present below an `O(n)` solution by storing the greatest elements from the right.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,50,6,10,2,3,1]

largest = [0 for i in range (len(x))] # temporary array to store, for every index i, the largest number from the right to index i
largest[-1] = x[-1]

ans = [] # list to store numbers satisfying condition
for i in range (len(x) - 2, -1, -1):
    if (x[i] > largest[i+1]):
        ans.append(x[i])
    largest[i] = max (x[i], largest[i+1])

for i in range (len(ans)-1,-1,-1): # print elements in the same order as given list
    print (ans[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of python's built in `sorted` method.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,50,6,3,2,3,8]
y = sorted(x, reverse=True) 
print(y[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are comparing an individual value against a whole list of values.  You will either have to make another loop or use the max() function on that sublist to get the highest value it contains.

A more efficient strategy is to process the list backwards while keeping track of the maximum number encountered.

By accumulating the maximum value backwards in the list and comparing it to the previous number, you can find all the numbers that are greater than all their successor.  This produces results in reverse but the `accumulate()` function from the itertools module can be used to get these reversed maximum and the zip() function will allow you to combine them with the numbers in the original list for comparison/selection purposes.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,50,6,3,2,3,8]

from itertools import accumulate

r = [n for n,m in zip(x[-2::-1],accumulate(x[::-1],max)) if n>m]
print(r)
[50]
```

This returns a list because, depending on the data, there could be multiple numbers satisfying the condition:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,50,6,3,2,3,1]

r = [n for n,m in zip(x[-2::-1],accumulate(x[::-1],max)) if n>m][::-1]
print(r)
[50, 6, 3]
```